# Restart while loop when selector for next page is clicked

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, while-loop, puppeteer

sorry but I am very new to coding and this is my first project, in which i chose to create a simple scraper for eBay using puppeteer. The program takes in the item to be searched and the desired amount of pages to scraped as a command line argument.
However, due to the selector children `li:nth-child` increasing each time, i had to create an incremental while loop to through said n-th children from 2 to 60.
This works for the first page, and outputs all items desired. However, due to having to scrape 2+ pages, the i value used in the loop must reset at the start of the next page to restart said loop.
I believe the pagination is correct as in headless mode, the second, third, etc. pages are clicked through.

current loop

```
let currentPage = 1;

while (currentPage <= pagestoScrape) {
    let content = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let data = [];
        let childnumber = 2;
        let i = 2;

        while (i < 60) {
            let itemids = document.querySelectorAll(`#srp-river-results > ul > li:nth-child(${childnumber}) > div`);
            itemids.forEach((itemid) => {
                let PRODUCT_ID = `#srp-river-results > ul > li:nth-child(${childnumber}) > div > div.s-item__info.clearfix > a > h3`;
                let PRODUCT_PRICE = `#srp-river-results > ul > li:nth-child(${childnumber}) > div > div.s-item__info.clearfix > div.s-item__details.clearfix > div:nth-child(1) > span`;
                let item = itemid.querySelector(PRODUCT_ID).innerText;
                let price = itemid.querySelector(PRODUCT_PRICE).innerText;
                data.push({
                    item,
                    price,
                });
            });
            childnumber++;
            i++;
        }
        return data;
    });

    let urls = [];
    urls = urls.concat(content);
    if (currentPage < pagestoScrape) {
        await Promise.all([
            await page.click('#srp-river-results > ul > div.srp-river-answer.srp-river-answer--BASIC_PAGINATION_V2 > div.s-pagination > span > span > nav > a.pagination__next.icon-link'),
            await page.waitForSelector('#srp-river-results > ul > div.srp-river-answer.srp-river-answer--BASIC_PAGINATION_V2 > div.s-pagination > span > span > nav > a.pagination__next.icon-link'),
        ])
    }

    currentPage++;
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(content, null, 1);
    fs.writeFileSync(`./output/output${item}.txt`, jsonData);
}
```

I have tried reavaluating i after the loop, during the promise and changing the loop to a for. I expected this to reset the loop and for the output to contain the results of each page. However, it results in the output of just 1 page, with no error.

Comment: The reset for `i` looks like it should occur each time `currentPage` is incremented. So, add `i=2` beneath `currentPage++;` at the foot of the outer `while` loop. Also, move the `let i=2` outside of the outer while-loop and place it at the top, along with `let currentPage = 1;`. I can't test your code so may have missed something but I think the structure I suggest should correctly reset `i`.

Comment: On closer look, the declaration of  an new `i` with `let i = 2` inside your outer `while` loop should reset it (even if it is computationally wasteful, one declaration above that loop is preferable) . The observed problem is likely due to subsequent commands being executed before one of your `await` blocks is complete but I can't spot it yet.

Comment: I suggest providing more context by showing the site you're working with and the expected result. There should be a cleaner and simpler way to achieve whatever you want to achieve here. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)

Comment: Hey guys thank you all for helping me and big shoutout to Mr. pritlove for all love (lol), I ended up the solving the issue by defining the list outside of the loops. :)